# Script to program periodic switch-on and off

Tags: bash, scripts, suspend, cron

My PC has a problem in its motherboard so when it's inactive for many hours after being on it won't start up, both when it's completely switched off or suspended. It takes between 8 to 18 hours to manage to start it up depending on how much work it had done previously.

So I figured it would be a solution never letting it be switched off or suspended, but completely active. The problem is this is a waste of energy. So I thought maybe it was possible to make a script that turns on and off the computer periodically. I guess it's impossible to turn it off completely because how is it going to execute the script if the computer is not switched on? So at least let it be suspended.

So what do you think? Is this achievable? I was thinking of using `crontab` and `shutdown` (or some similar command to suspend or hibernate) but I am not sure how to do this.

Any suggestion?

Comment: that's not what I am asking, I want to try what I am saying first. Do motherboards grow on trees?

Comment: If the computer is connected to a wired network you may consider WoL (wake on LAN) if the BIOS supports it. The PC shouldn't be completely shut down but on stand-by. You could have another computer wake the PC periodically, or even use an [app from your smartphone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benfinnigan.wol). For a timed shutdown to standby, use `cron`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rtcwake` should be able to help you out here.

```
sudo rtcwake -m mem -s 15
```

That should enter a S3 (memory) suspend for a few seconds, all your fans will shut off... And then and then boot right back up again without any state loss. Even network connections remain intact here.

There is also a `-m off` mode. I'm going to assume you lose state completely here and AFAIK, only some BIOSes are equipped to power on from an off-state from RTC. Might be worth a shot if S3 doesn't work.

---

You can automate that with cron. Run `sudo crontab -e` and add something like:

```
0 */4 * * * rtcwake -m mem -s 15
```

That will run every four hours. It'll annoy the hell out of anybody using it when it goes to sleep, but that's apparently what you want.

---

But in all seriousness, this doesn't sound like a healthy underlying issue.

You might do well to fix or replace the broken parts, or at least diagnose it properly. You might be able to fix the problem completely or at least get it to the point that so when it does finally die, you know what needs replacing.

These things have a habit of kicking the bucket when you most need them.

Comment: can I sleep if for a longer time? like 2-3 hours. And to enable and disable this script just modifying the cron file right?

Comment: @dabadaba Sure! The `-s` argument takes seconds (so `-s 10800` for three hours) or you can use `-t` to specify a time. See `man rtcwake`. You should test this with something short first though. Not all motherboards support waking via the RTC.

Comment: regarding your edit, the motherboard is fried anyway, so what's the harm?

Comment: My point in the last section is to point out that this either might not be as dire as it sounds (eg just a worn fan bearing that seizes up) that's currently trivial to fix. It might be completely terminal. Getting that diagnostic done now (while it still just-about-works) might save you some money and downtime in the future.

Comment: I took it to the repair shop and they said it was definetly the motherboard

Comment: hey it's been a while since I use `crontab`. I am using the command `sudo crontab -e` to edit the file and then just testing its use with this line: `* * * * * echo "hey"` and then saved but it does not appear to be working. I thought `cron` would start working right away after saving the file, do I need to do something else? Also what does `*/4` mean? I don't get how how that's three hours. How can I set a period? Like I don't know every hour and a half.

Comment: Cron runs things in an *essentially* shell-less environment. You won't see output on your current terminal. `*/4` is every four whatever-unit-we're-in. I changed it but not the text, my bad.

Comment: yeah thanks! before you could answer I realized echo wouldn't send any output to the open terminal, so I tried other command instead and I saw it worked. Ok! now I understand how to set periods thanks. By the way, for the same purpose would it be the same to make a bash file and wrap the command in a while loop and sleep for the desired time?